# FOSUserBundle: UniqueEntity annotation throws: The field "User" is not mapped by Doctrine, so it cannot be validated for uniqueness

Tags: symfony, doctrine, fosuserbundle

I have an entity `Employee` with foreign key from `User`.
I'm using FOSUserBundle.

I want to achieve a unique one-to-one relation between `User` and `Employee`.

I tried to add the `UniqueEntity` annotation but I got the following error:

> "The field "User" is not mapped by Doctrine, so it cannot be validated for uniqueness."

I found out that the problem is that the `User` entity uses ...

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
```

... instead of ...

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
```

But I don't know what I must override because this Entity in bundle doesn't exists..

```
/**
 * Employee
 * @ORM\Table(name="employee")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity(
 * fields={"User"},
 * errorPath="User",
 * message="This account is assigned"
 * )
 */
class Employee {

    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id",unique=true)
     * })
     */
    private $myUser;
```

}

```
namespace App\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }   
    function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getUsername() {
        return $this->username;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're referencing the **class-name** instead of the **property-name** inside the `Employee` class in your `@UniqueEntity` definition for `fields`.

The correct configuration for the annotation would be `fiels={"myUser"}` instead of `User`.

```php
/**
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *   fields={
 *     "myUser"
 *   },
 *   errorPath="myUser",
 *   message="This account is assigned"
 * )
 */
class Employee {

    /**
     * [..]
     */
    private $myUser;
```